# jQuery: Click to hide element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small jQuery function below. It basically works by clicking on the element `#hover-trigger`, whether is be a link or image. This then makes a centralized div element
appear centrally on screen, in this case `#hover-content`.

What I am wondering is, what function can I add onto the end of this one to make the `div` disappear again when a certain element is clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hover-trigger').click(function()
    {
        $(this).next('#hover-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');                  

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else 
            $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    })
});
```

Comment: Retagging, there is no relevance to PHP in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever element you want to click on, tell it to hide the div.

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){

$("#divToHide").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#hide-trigger').click(function(){
    $('.avtive').slideToggle();
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');
});
```

or am I missing something?